# Restore got failed in sql server

Tags: restore, ssms, corruption

While i restore my database i got the below error. But i have more space in my drive.

**modify file encountered error 112 (Ther is not enough space on the disk)while attempting to expand the physical file C:\xys.mdf**

Comment: You might have space, but you do not have **enough** space.

Comment: yes, i have more space. backup is 20gb. available space is 500gb

Comment: Probably you have not enough rights to modify the file. It's a strange location (C:\xyz.mdf) where your database file is...........

Comment: Correct what you are telling.For example i put location is  c drive. Actual backfile in H drive from different server

Comment: Try to restore to a different directory, like 'C:\TEMP\xys.mdf'.